# Data fetch from VIEWS instead of Tables in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, view

We have created one view and we are trying to fetch the data from that view but getting this error

> DataTables warning (table id = 'grid'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0

How to solve this ?

```
if (!class_exists('DemographicAnalyticsviews')) { 
   class DemographicAnalyticsviews extends TTS_Record { 
       public function getAdminAccess()
       { 
           return array("get","element","save","delete"); 
       }

       public function getUserAccess()
       { 
           return array(); 
       } 
       var $_table = 'demo_analytics_vw'; // This one is view name. 
    } 
 } 


static function table($newtable = false)
{
    static $_table;

    if (!empty($newtable))  $_table = $newtable;
    if (empty($_table)) $_table = 'adodb_logsql';
    return $_table;
}
```

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: yes wait please

Comment: if (!class_exists('DemographicAnalyticsviews')) {
    class DemographicAnalyticsviews extends TTS_Record {
        public function getAdminAccess(){
            return array("get","element","save","delete");
        }

        public function getUserAccess(){
            return array();
        }

        var $_table = 'demo_analytics_vw'; // This one is view name.
    }
}

Comment: @DipakChatterjee not in the comments, add code to question

Comment: ok. Adding code in the question

Comment: It is working when we are using a table name.

Comment: The second function is for the table support. Can we write a function for the views also?